# NavMesh Rigidbody navigation system stutters around corners

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

### Problem

I have created a navigation system using Rigidbody and NavMesh. There is an agent that tries to follow me around. It has a capsule collider, a script (see below), a Rigidbody, and a NavMeshAgent component. It works by running the NavMesh calculations, getting the coordinates for the next place to move, disabling the NavMesh, and moving there using `MovePosition()`. This system works pretty well usually, but lately I have been experiencing problems. When the Agent moves around an obstacle, it pauses on the corners. I believe the reason for this is my code, especially my `MovePosition()` function, but I don't know how to fix it.

https://vimeo.com/731216013

### Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float m_Speed = 3f;
    public Transform goal;
    public NavMeshAgent navMesh;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveToNextPosition();
    }

    void MoveToNextPosition()
    {
        navMesh.enabled = true;

        if (navMesh.isOnNavMesh)
        {
            NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
            if(navMesh.CalculatePath(goal.position, path))
            {
                navMesh.path = path;
            }
        }

        Vector3 pos = navMesh.steeringTarget;
        navMesh.enabled = false;


        //Store user input as a movement vector
        Vector3 distance = pos - transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = distance.normalized;
        float speed = rb.velocity.magnitude;

        Debug.Log(direction);
        
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * m_Speed);
     
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a big list of what the issues with the navmesh can be, hence I am posting it as an answer:

Open your navigation panel, if you can't find one or accidentally closed the tab, go to **Window > AI > Navigation**. The Navigation tab looks like this:

[image]

Open the **Bake** tab and set your agent's radius and height according to its dimensions. At the bottom, click to expand **Advanced** options. In that, there's a field **Min Region Area**, increasing the value increases the area around the static obstacles where the navmesh agent cannot move.